# What kind of basis is associated with polar coordinates?

Tags: polar-coordinates, change-of-basis

I have trouble understanding polar coordinates, because they do not seem to be associated with a fixed basis like cartesian coordinates do. One example so you guys can see where I'm struggling.

If we are given the canonical basis $(e_1, e_2)$ of $\mathbb R^2$ and $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ then we can define $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ as the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $e_1$ (which can also be written as $f_{e_1}$).

And it works because $e_1$ is the same for all $(x,y)$. That means $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_1,y_1)$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_2,y_2)$ are derivative with respect to the same direction, that is $e_1$.

However, how can we define $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}$ or even $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}$? Indeed, if I write $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}(r_1, \theta _1)$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}(r_2, \theta _2)$ how can I know what is direction of the vector we are derivating, since the basis at point $(r_1, \theta _1)$ is not the same as the basis at point $(r_2, \theta _2)$ (since $e_r$ will change with $\theta$).
I'm not even sure if I should be talking of basis since polar coordinates clearly don't correspond to the kind of basis we are used to in linear algebra.

I've looked around for a thorough explanation of this kind of stuff without success. The most helpful thing was the article [Curvilinear Coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvilinear_coordinates) on Wikipedia, but wasn't that helpful.

**To make a clear question : How is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}$ defined?** And how should I understand it?

Comment: My problem is not how to use polar coordinates, and I know it "works". I can solve the problems just right. My question would be why does it work?

Comment: I'm going to be more accurate. We do not need to know $e_r$ to find the result. Because when you write $f(r,\theta)$, $(r,\theta)$ is already in the polar coordinates basis.

Comment: We can associate with every polar coordinate an ordered pair $(\theta, r)$ and every possible polar coordinate would be a linear combination of $(0,1), (1,0)$, where the first entry is the angle from the diagonal and the second entry is the distance from the origin.

Comment: Just to be clear, how do you define (rigorously) $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}$ ? And I get it when you say that derivatives are basis independent, when you try to calculate them. At least I understand it when you take two basis that are regular basis of vector fields.

Comment: @KiwiKiwi Think of the $r$-$\theta$ coordinate system as a completely separate Cartesian plane instead of a different labeling applied to the $x$-$y$ plane. Let $\phi:(r,\theta)\mapsto(x,y)$ be the polar-to-rectangular mapping. From that point of view, what you’re asking about is $(f\circ\phi)_r$, which is a straightforward application of the chain rule.

Comment: @amd Okay I think that's one very simple way to solve the issue.

Comment: A way to look at it that doesn’t involve a separate space: a partial derivative is just a directional derivative taken in a direction that is considered special for some reason. For derivatives w/r $x$ and $y$, those directions are fixed; for $r$ and $\theta$, the directions depend on the location where the derivative is being taken. Not quite as simple as the pullback/chain-rule view, but it might give you a better feel for local frames that can vary from point to point.